# Retain chosen tags when navigating tag filter options

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, new-nav

When i change to custom tags and enter some tags. then change to all and back to custom tags all input from the first time are removed.

I think it will be better if the changes will be saved and shown at next time  `custom tags` is selected.

Comment: @Downvoter: please explain why